# How base R `qr` creates the QR decomposition compact form?

Tags: r, qr-decomposition

I was wondering how to return the 'compact' form from QR decomposition using `RcppArmadillo`.  It is relatively simple to run a QR decomposition on a matrix using `RcppArmadillo` with the following:

```
library(inline)

src <- '
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
mat X = as<mat>(A);
mat Q, R;

qr(Q,R,X);

return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("Q")=Q,Rcpp::Named("R")=R);
'

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(A = "matrix"), src, plugin="RcppArmadillo")
```

However, when I compare the output of `fun` to the normal R `qr` method I am stumped by the 'compact' matrix returned by `qr$qr`.

```
mat <- matrix(seq(9), 3)

# Armadillo method
fun(mat)
$Q
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.2672612  0.8728716  0.4082483
[2,] -0.5345225  0.2182179 -0.8164966
[3,] -0.8017837 -0.4364358  0.4082483

$R
          [,1]      [,2]          [,3]
[1,] -3.741657 -8.552360 -1.336306e+01
[2,]  0.000000  1.963961  3.927922e+00
[3,]  0.000000  0.000000  2.220446e-15

# normal R method
qr(mat)$qr
           [,1]      [,2]          [,3]
[1,] -3.7416574 -8.552360 -1.336306e+01
[2,]  0.5345225  1.963961  3.927922e+00
[3,]  0.8017837  0.988693  1.776357e-15
```

I have tried looking a the old Fortran in the R source `dqrdc2.f` but I am not a strong Fortran programmer and cannot figure out how this compact form is created.  Similar questions were asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031215/mystified-by-qr-q-what-is-an-orthonormal-matrix-in-compact-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964047/qr-decomposition-in-rcpparmadillo) but I haven't found a solution to this.  The ultimate goal here is to have:

```
all.equal(fun(mat), qr(mat)$qr)
```

where clearly the output of `fun` would be modified if I can learn about this compact form.

**EDIT**

The documentation for `qr` reports:

```
Value

The QR decomposition of the matrix as computed by 
LINPACK or LAPACK. The components in the returned value correspond 
directly to the values returned by DQRDC/DGEQP3/ZGEQP3.

qr  
a matrix with the same dimensions as x. The upper triangle contains the 
\bold{R} of the decomposition and the lower triangle contains information 
on the \bold{Q} of the decomposition (stored in compact form). Note that 
the storage used by DQRDC and DGEQP3 differs.
```

This "lower triangle" is what I want to understand.

Comment: Have you looked at `help(qr)` in R, and particularly entry on _Value_ for `qr`?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, yes that is why I somewhat confused.  I understand the upper triangle but I don't understand the lower triangle compact form.

Comment: That's fine, but methinks you have a _base R_ question and not an (Rcpp)Armadillo question.  Methinks if you tried Octave or NumPy you'd probably get the same QR as from RcppArmadillo.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, fair enough, I can remove the those extra tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the compact form returned by `qr`, but you can easily just extract the `Q` and `R` matrices from the object:

```
qr.Q(qr(mat))
qr.R(qr(mat))
```

You'll find that they match what is returned by Rcpp.

I looked at the manual, but I can't make heads or tails out of it. The actual function for `qr.Q` just calls a Fortran function, which I'm not able to parse.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was aware of those two functions but I was curious how the compact form was made.  I will leave this question open to see if anyone does know.